# Disable all future days in React-Day-Picker?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I have a date range calendar using react-day-picker. It works beautifully aside from me not being able to disable "all" future days from the selection. The api docs show that you can enter a single day or multiple days but not all future days?

```
      <DayPicker
        disabledDays={new Date()} // how to disable all days after today?
        modifiers={{
          sunday: day => day.getDay() === 0,
          firstOfMonth: day => day.getDate() === 1
        }}
        onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
        onDayMouseEnter={this.handleDayMouseEnter}
      />
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/issues/644

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `disabledDays` prop can also be a function: `(day: Date) ⇒ boolean` so you should be able to do something like:

```
disabledDays={day => day > (new Date())}
```

Answer (score 10):

A slightly better version is

```
const today = new Date();
<DayPicker
  disabledDays={{ after: today }}
  selectedDays={new Date()}
/>
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/l942z0w9y9

Comment: Is it possible we add double after ?

Comment: ah I found it,  `disabledDays: [
              { after: new Date(moment()) }, { after: to }
            ]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
<DayPicker
        toDate={new Date()}
    />
```

More info: https://react-day-picker.js.org/basics/navigation#between-months-or-dates

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Solves it elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

2023 update:
To disable date, use disabled attribute in the daypicker component

Example

```html
<DayPicker
        disabled={{ after: new Date(), before:"" }} />
```

you can provide after for disabling the dates which present after the given date and you can provide before for disabling the dates which present before the given date.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will be useful to disable,

> selected future days

> disable all days before the current day

> weekends (Saturdays and Sundays)

**Way 1:**

*The API response is an array of objects.*

```
import DayPicker from "react-day-picker";
import moment from "moment";
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

const selectedDaysToDisable = [];

const arr = [
    { id: 1, date: "Sep 28 2021 10:00:00 AM" },
    { id: 2, date: "Sep 29 2021 08:00:00 AM" },
    { id: 3, date: "Oct 5 2021 08:00:00 AM" }
  ];

arr.map((val) => {
    return selectedDaysToDisable.push(dateFormat(val.date));
});

function dateFormat(date) {
    return new Date(
        moment(date).format("MM") +
        "/" +
        moment(date).format("DD") +
        "/" +
        moment(date).format("YYYY")
    );
  }

<DayPicker
 disabledDays={[
      { before: new Date() },
      { daysOfWeek: [0, 6] },
      ...selectedDaysToDisable
    ]}
/>
```

**Way 2:**

*For simple understanding.*

```
const selectedDaysToDisable = [new Date(2021, 8, 28), new Date(2021, 8, 23), new Date(2021, 8, 29)];
<DayPicker
    disabledDays={[
        { before: new Date() },
        { daysOfWeek: [0, 6] },
        ...selectedDaysToDisable
    ]}
/>
```